# Override fs functions

Tags: node.js, mocking, cypress, fs, stub

I am doing some E2E tests using Cypress.

Since it doesnt support node functions such as those from `fs`, I have mocked them as below.

In my test file:

```
window.Cypress.fs = require('fs')
window.Cypress.fs.existsSync = () => { return true // custom return }
window.Cypress.fs.lstatSync = () => { // custom return }
```

But now I am getting some error:

```
fs.lstatSync(...).isFile is not a function
```

How can I override/mock/stub `isFile()`?

I tried doing:

```
window.Cypress.fs.lstatSync.isFile = () => { return true }
//and
window.Cypress.fs.lstatSync().isFile = () => { return true }
```

But it doesn't work.

Here is my source code (not the mock):

```
return fs.lstatSync(filePath).isFile()
```

Any thoughts??

Comment: did you tried `window.Cypress.fs.lstatSync = () => { return { isFile(){return true}  } }`?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon - omg thank you, this is working! How could I miss that?! Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you execute `lstatSync()` and then use its results, you need to write:

```js
window.Cypress.fs.lstatSync = () => { 
  return { 
    isFile() { return true }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to mock the [fs.Stats class](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats) and, at a minimum, its .isFile() method, to do what you want. fs.lstatSync returns an instance of fs.Stats.